# VB.net - Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens report wrong bound sizes when using any DPI scaling above 125%, anyway to fix this?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, dpi

I have my vb.net application (written in  VS2010 pro) setup to detect and support multi-monitor setups at various DPI scaling.

I use Screen.AllScreens.Length to get me how many monitors I have running:

```
Public Function getMonitorCount() As Integer
    Return Screen.AllScreens.Length
End Function
```

And then I loop through all the monitors to get their various info:

```
Public Sub getMonitorSetupFull()
    m = getMonitorCount()
    n = 0
    Do While n < m
        Monitor(n) = Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens(n)
        XLeft(n) = Monitor(n).Bounds.X
        YTop(n) = Monitor(n).Bounds.Y
        XRight(n) = XLeft(n) + Monitor(n).Bounds.Width
        YBottom(n) = YTop(n) + Monitor(n).Bounds.Height
        MonitorSize(n) = New Size(Monitor(n).Bounds.Width, Monitor(n).Bounds.Height)
        n = n + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

I'm having an issue where Monitor(n).Bounds (aka Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens(n).Bounds) give me the wrong values at high DPI. For example, at 200% DPI Monitor(n).Bounds.Height gives me a value of 540 for a 1080p monitor (precisely half). At 100%/125% DPI, I get at 1080 which is correct but at 126% DPI I get 857 instead of 1080.

Is there something I can add to my code to get Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens(n).Bounds to detect the proper sizes at these DPI or should I just manually compensate for this eccentric behavior myself via something along the lines of if DPI > 125%, Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens(n).Bounds.Height = Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens(n).Bounds.Height * DPIratio ?

**UPDATE:** To confound this issue even more, I found that if I select use Windows XP DPI scaling while I'm setting the DPI, this issue doesn't occur. Nor does it occur when I'm not using Aero. I've reproduced this on other Windows 7 machines.

Comment: I am dealing with the same issue, almost 2 years later. Did you ever find a solution? I have tried getting the dpi of each monitor and then adjusting the resolution accordingly, but this gets inconsistent results.